# Using the Hardy- Littlewood maximal function in a initial value problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the initial value problem

$$
\begin{cases}
\partial^{2}_{t} w - \Delta w = 0, \\[6pt]
w(x,0) = 0\\[6pt]
\partial_t w(x,0) = g(x)
\end{cases}
$$

$x \in R^3 , t \in R.$

if $g$ is a radial function, i know this

$$w(x,t) = w(\| x\|,t) = \frac{1}{2 \| x\|}  \int_{ |\|x\| - t|}^{\| x\|+t} \rho g(\rho) \  d\rho.$$
The exercise is:

Use the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function to show that

$$ \left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \| w(\cdot,t)\|^2_\infty \ dt\right)^{1/2} \leq C \|g\|_2.$$

I have no idea to how to do that. someone can help me with this exercise ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Hardy-Littlewood maximal operator acts from $L^p$ to $L^p$ as follows: for $f\in L^p$: $Mf = \sup_{r>0} \frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)} |f(y)|dy.$ It is well-known that $\|Mf\|_p \leq C \|f\|_p$ that means the H-L operator is bounded from $L^p$ to $L^p$. Btw. revise your question, could it be that you have some typos?

Comment: the question is right ( i copied form the book ) .I believe that  $||w( . , t )||_{\infty} = M(g)$. Do you know prove that ? Do you know if my affirmation is true ?

Comment: Where did you get the formula for $w(x,t)$?  See Proposition 4 in S. Klainerman and M. Machedon, Space time estimates for null forms and the local existence theorem, Communications of Pure and Applied Math., 46, (1993), 1221-1268.  They have $|\|x\|-t|$ for the lower limit.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith you're right. i did a mistake. i fixed the error . thanks to show to me the error ( my english is terrible , sorry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$w(x,t) = w(\| x\|,t) = \frac{1}{2 \| x\|}  \int_{ |\|x\| - t|}^{\| x\|+t} \rho g(\rho) \  d\rho.$$
So
$$ |w(\| x\|,t)| \le \frac{1}{2 \| x\|}  \int_{ t-\|x\|}^{t+\| x\|} |\rho g(\rho)| \  d\rho.$$
This is trivial if $t > \|x\|$, and if $t \le \|x\|$ it follows because
$$ |w(\| x\|,t)| \le \frac{1}{2 \| x\|}  \int_{ \|x\|-t}^{\| x\|+t} |\rho g(\rho)| \  d\rho \le \frac{1}{2 \| x\|}  \int_{ t-\|x\|}^{t+\| x\|} |\rho g(\rho)| \  d\rho,$$
because the integrand is positive.

Thus by the definition of the one-dimensional Hardy-Littlewood maximal function,
$\|w(\cdot,t)\| \le M h(t)$, where $h(s) = |sg(s)| $.  Now use spherical coordinates to see that $\|g\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^3)} = \|h\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}$.

Comment: By the way, Klainerman and Machedon show the result isn't necessarily true if $g$ isn't radially symmetric.  I extended this to show the result still isn't true if the $L^\infty$ norm is replaced by the BMO norm.  http://www.math.missouri.edu/~stephen/preprints/schrod.html, Time decay for the bounded mean oscillation of solutions of the Schrödinger and wave equations. Duke Math J. 91 (1998), 393-408.

Comment: Hello Stephen Montgomery-Smith. It's so nice this solution. Thank you. And, just one more question, this solution above is just for the case $\|x\| - t <= 0$, and what if do and the other case?

Comment: It still works if $\|x\|-t < 0$, it is just that the equality turns into an inequality.  That is why I added the absolute value inside the integral.

Comment: I asked because in the formula of $w$ we have $| \|x\| - t |$ in the lower limit, and you analyzed the case $\|x\| - t \leq 0$. And the case $\|x\| - t \geq 0$?

Comment: I meant to say it still works for $\|x\|-t > 0$.

Comment: In the case $\|x\| - t > 0$, the length is $2t$ and we have $2\|x\|$ in the denominator, therefore we don't have the maximal function $Mh$ as previously, right? Excuse me for thats questions, I really need to learn this.

Comment: See my edit in the answer where I tackle your question explicitly.

Comment: Oh, I really understand now. Thank you VERY MUCH! You saved my life, rs. Thank you for explain me that. =D